# The regular expression to find multiple words in a certain string

Tags: regex, hadoop

I just begin learning regular expression and hadoop mapreduce. Now I am trying to run a hadoop mapreduce example application called "grep" and I would like to find a series of words like "and" "is" "are" "the" in a text input file. One of the input argument of the application "grep" is the regular expression which define the words you want to find. Let's say I want search for following words: "and" "is" "are" "the". Could any one give me an example for how to set up the regular expression as the input argument for the grep?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `grep` is recognized:

```
hadoop org.apache.examples.Grep <indir> <outdir> <regex>
```

So you could start off with something as simple as:

```
hadoop org.apache.examples.Grep <indir> <outdir> '(and)|(is)|(are)|(the)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should be:

"\b(and|is|are|the)\b"

Put that as your regex argument.

You can put more words-to-find between || which is an "or".

The "\b" means a word boundary, without \b, you could match a word inside another word for example: "scared" instead of "are" since "are" is contained in "scared".